# 'adb' is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: android, react-native, adb

When trying to build a react native project I'm getting this error on the command `react-native run-android`. But when I searched this ,found a solution that to set the `system_variables` but  after trying it I'm still getting the same error I can't do further because of this error.Please help me to figure this out.

[image: adb command error]

Answer (score 2):

Add the following lines to your $HOME/.bash_profile config file:**FOR LINUX**

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

### > **Type source $HOME/.bash_profile to load the config into your current shell**

Configure the ANDROID_HOME environment variable ( **FOR WINDOW**)
[PLEASE CHECK THIS LINK FOR WINDDOW](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#3-configure-the-android-home-environment-variable)

Then Verify that ANDROID_HOME has been added to your path by running echo $PATH. 
**Make sure you follow these step correctly**

Comment: The OP is using Windows.

Comment: added link for windows Alex P

Answer (score -1):

When you get this message even when you type adb in a normal console window, you should put adb.exe in your PATH variable under 'system environment variables'.